# Is it possible to share a speaker line as ground?

Tags: microcontroller, amplifier, current-sink

Given the following circuit, how can I use terminal 3 to detect when the button has been pushed?

Everything right of the 3 pin terminal is a manufactured device- the [Aiphone LE-D](https://www.aiphone.com/home/products/le-d).
(Also note it's possible I got the capacitor polarity incorrect. I do have audio coming out from the speaker.)

I know there's no ground on the amp's negative terminal (makes sense) so I can't sink current from the microcontroller through terminal 3.

Can I tie the amp negative to ground without hurting the amplifier so that I can sink current through the push button?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: In general: no, you cannot. Your amplifier might be a [bridged amp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridged_and_paralleled_amplifiers).

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case. Any conjecture then on Aiphone's original intent of this circuit?

Comment: If it's a bridged amp then pin 1 will sometimes go above ground, so you *could* try to make current flow through pin 3. (Make sure it's actually a bridged amp or this might not work)

Comment: they would use a single-ended amplifier such a s LM386 presumably with a 12V supply (seeing as all ther euipment uses 12V)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I didn't know that was a thing but now this all makes so much sense. I'll look into this amp instead of my MAX98357A.